docker-composeの"I have no name!"といわれるエラーについて
現在の状態
Rocket.Chatの運用を行いたいと思い、【実は無料で使えます】Rocket.Chat構築とおススメ設定方法を参考にして、Rocket.Chatを起動させました。
その中で、mongodbの中身はどのようになっているのかを知りたくなり、起動しているコンテナに入って、見てみようと思い以下のコマンドを実行しました。
docker exec  -it rocketchat-mongodb-1 bash

無事にコンテナには入れましたが、ユーザ名のところが"i have no name!"となっており、sudoが使えない状態となっています。
I have no name!@83ebf6aa9a88:/$

やったこと
Dockerファイルを作成し、ユーザを作成するようにしましたが、
FROM registry.rocket.chat/rocketchat/rocket.chat:${RELEASE:-6.13.0}

USER root  # root権限で実行

# 既存のnodeユーザーを新しいグループに追加
RUN groupadd -g 1000 mygroup || true && \
    usermod -a -G mygroup node

USER node  # 既存のnodeユーザーに切り替え

以下のようなエラーになりました
docker-compose build
[+] Building 2.8s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 331B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => WARN: UndefinedArgInFrom: FROM argument 'RELEASE' is not declared (line 1)                                                                                                                              0.2s
 => [internal] load metadata for registry.rocket.chat/rocketchat/rocket.chat:6.13.0                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.2s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM registry.rocket.chat/rocketchat/rocket.chat:6.13.0                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN groupadd -g 1000 mygroup || true &&     usermod -a -G mygroup node                                                                                                                      1.3s
------
 > [2/2] RUN groupadd -g 1000 mygroup || true &&     usermod -a -G mygroup node:
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c groupadd -g 1000 mygroup || true &&     usermod -a -G mygroup node" did not complete successfully: unable to find user root  # root権限で実行: no matching entries in passwd file


知りたいこと

I have no name!ではなく、dockerホストと同じ情報のアカウントでログインして、sudoがつかえるようにしたい。

情報が足りなければ、おっしゃっていただけたら載せます。
どうか、よろしくお願いいたします。

参考: How to use sudo inside a docker container?

https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#format

BuildKit treats lines that begin with # as a comment,


A # marker anywhere else in a line is treated as an argument.

Dockerfileの記述で、コメントとなるのは #で始まる行 です
行の中の#はargumentと扱われます
USER root  # root権限で実行

と書いたら root  # root権限で実行 というユーザを使おうとしますね

（本筋ではないかもですが、I have no name! と出るのは意図的に非特権ユーザをデフォルトにしているからで、それは制作者の意図通りの動作であってエラーと呼ぶのは違和感があります）

なるほど。。。そういう仕様だったのですね。rootでログインすることができました。
ありがとうございます。
